# Can't turn on bluetooth once it is turned off

Tags: dell, bluetooth

I'm using ubuntu 15.10, kernel version 4.2.0-25.
My laptop is Dell Inspiron 14-3452

The problem is that I can't turn bluetooth back on once I disable it.
The only way to turn enable it is to reboot.

```
rfkill list
```

shows no soft block or hard block

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

returns

```
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

ifconfig shows the hci0 bluetooth device, but when I type in lsusb it doesn't show any bluetooth devices

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5683 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b739 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg | grep Bluetooth returns

```
dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    2.673842] usb 1-2.1: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    5.317495] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    5.317534] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.317541] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.317548] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.317558] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.530006] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.530012] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.530020] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.673210] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[    5.673218] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[    5.675249] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    8.617443] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.617460] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.617474] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 3627.862044] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 3627.862047] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 3627.862911] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 6283.018539] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff880147d5c840 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 6360.048608] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8801438f6900 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 7193.045144] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff880143bebc00 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 7596.035702] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8801438c03c0 failed to resubmit (113)
```

I've tried rfkill unblock bluetooth, editing  /etc/rc.local and nothing  works.

Comment: try turning on after running this command `sudo  modprobe btusb && sleep 5`. report if it works or not

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: tried enabling via the panel and hciconfig

Comment: Any update on this? I have the exact same problem.